# How do I make the inline form be in the same line as the buttons?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am making an app with Bootstrap 4. I have 3 buttons and an inline form, and I want the inline form to be in the same line as the buttons. Currently with this code the form is below the buttons. How can I make everything be in the same line?

```
<button type="button" class="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-primary">
    <span>Agregar</span>
</button>
<div class="d-inline dropdown">
  <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="menuUtilidades" type="button" class="mr-2 mb-2 dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary">Utilidades</button>
</div>
<div class="d-inline dropdown">
  <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="menuReportes" type="button" class="mb-2 dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary">Reportes</button>
</div>
<form class="mb-2 form-inline">
  <!-- form that should be in same line -->
</form>
```

Comment: Just a heads up-- `--!>` is not how you close an html comment-- you can see in your code example that `</form>` is still in the comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `d-inline` to your form

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-primary">
    <span>Agregar</span>
  </button>
  <div class="d-inline dropdown">
    <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="menuUtilidades" type="button"
      class="mr-2 mb-2 dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary">Utilidades</button>
  </div>
  <div class="d-inline dropdown">
    <button aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="menuReportes" type="button"
      class="mb-2 dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary">Reportes</button>
  </div>
  <form class="mb-2 form-inline d-inline">
    my form
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't work, but d-inline-flex worked

Comment: Is your final result should same as my anser fiddle?

Comment: It should be d-inline-flex instead of d-inline